# Codeigniter + Ajax(jquery) quiz

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm in the process of developing a quiz for children. I need help to add ajax and jquery to process data instead of fetching a full page. Just fetching within one page. The problem is to change the $quiz to load into a JSON then to load into ajax Adding event handlers and so on. Help would be appreciated... New to programming....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We need a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a specific problem you are having in order to be able to help. Please read the [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for more information.

Comment: I, need help changing the application to use ajax/jquery. From, what strictly needs changing is the application load only in a single page. Changing the controller and view to use jquery/ajax to get the quiz to view questions and the answers.

Comment: This is too broad of a question for StackOverflow. It needs to be a specific programming problem. [See this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for examples of questions that are a good fit for this site.

Comment: The problem is to change the $quiz to load into a JSON then to load into ajax

Comment: I understand that's what you're trying to do, but it's not a programming _problem_. You're not encountering a specific bug or error that we can help you with. We'd be more than happy to assist with a specific issue once the project is far enough along. In the meanwhile, I suggest cracking open jQuery, AngularJS, or React tutorials. Good luck!

Comment: I need help now please this has to be done in time for Christmas. Could you help me with this please

Comment: I cannot; StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, or meant to provide broad project guidance. Please seek out a developer, or try another site, forum, or chat room that's designed to handle questions of this nature.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're more looking for a basic overview of how AJAX interacts with different things. If you're working in CodeIgniter, you're clearly familiar with the MVC programming model, where:

`controller -> makes my decisions`

`model      -> interacts with my database, etc`

`view       -> displays my information`

So, instead of ever page being a refresh and following that path, you want to implement AJAX to load the content you need back into your view, more like:

`controller           -> loads model and view`

`model                -> interacts with database, etc`

`view                 -> displays my information`

`AJAX with JavaScript -> Loads a new controller path`

`secondary model      -> loads new information`

`secondary view       -> returns to be displayed on first view`

Your starting point would be to set up your controllers, models, and views to create the access points you want.

Say, for instance, you wanted to dynamically load a set of rendered questions based on which quiz your user selects. You would have one main view (we can call it dashboard). We'll use a controller to load the main view called `dashboard.php`

#### Dashboard.php

The Dashboard.php controller will default load our main view.

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    /**
    * Dashboard index() function loads by default 
    * and shows our dashboard view.
    */
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('dashboard-view.php');
    }

}
```

#### dashboard-view.php

We'll use the dashboard-view to do two things. Set up a basic page architecture, provide links to load our quiz questions via AJAX, and load a loadQuiz.js which will make the AJAX Calls

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Quiz</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">jquery.min.js</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">quizLoader.js</script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-quiz="1" class="loader">Load Quiz 1</a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-quiz="2" class="loader">Load Quiz 2</a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-quiz="3" class="loader">Load Quiz 3</a>

    <div id="questions">
        [we will load our questions here]
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

#### loadQuiz.js

Our loadQuiz.js will have an event listener attached to our `.loader` anchor tags. It will then read the `data-quiz` attribute and send off an AJAX request to load questions for that quiz id. Once the handler finishes, we will place the data into the `<div id="questions" />` to display to the user.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    // Event Listener for Anchor Tags with .loader class
    $( document ).on('click', '.loader', function() {

        var target = $( '#questions' );

        var quizID = $( this ).attr( 'data-quiz' );
        var datastring = '?quizID=' + quizID;

        // Send our AJAX REQUEST
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path-to-ajax-controller',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datastring,
            async: true,
            success: function(response) { // put our response in our target
                target.html(response);
            },
            error: function(e) { // Show an error if we got one
                target.html( 'Failed to load: ' + e.responseText );
            }
        });

    });

} );
```

Now we need to address loading the actual quiz content. So we'll just use a second controller and simple view to create that data we want to return to the AJAX call.

#### ajax.php

Controller to load our questions and deliver to a simple view. This assumes you have a model that will load your questions out of a database or otherwise. The end result is that `$data['html']` should be `<html>` markup.

Note below the `$data['html']` is just getting output via an `echo` statement, but you could load it into another view file for formatting. The bottom line here is that whatever would be displayed by this function is what will be returned as the `response` in our `$.ajax()` function.

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

    /*
    * This function should be called by the url we specificed in our
    * $.ajax() call in our loadQuiz.js
    * you can do this with the CI routes if you need to
    */
    function loadQuiz() {
        $this->load->model('quiz_model'); // Have a function here for loading your quiz itself

        $quiz_id = $_POST['quizID'];
        $data['html'] = $this->quiz_model->renderQuestions($quiz_id);

        echo $data['html'];

    }

}
```

I hope this helps a little bit. Good luck!

Comment: thank you lionel. What is your personal email. So, I could ask you things in the future. Your a brilliant architect.